# Nest Js Microservice Keep-Alive TCP connection

Tags: tcp, nestjs, amazon-ecs, nlb

I have a basic Nest Js application HTTP server and one Microservice Nest Js application using TCP transport.

I am sending an HTTP request to my HTTP server that sends event messages through TCP to my microservice and it's working perfectly.

I have deployed these 2 applications on AWS ECS Using Copilot, the HTTP one is configured as an Application Load Balancer and the microservice is configured as Network Load Balancer

After some time of inactivity, my TCP connection is ending because of NLB TCP timeout, so I would to know if there is a way to use the Keep-Alive feature directly with Nest JS.

Does there is another solution to keep the connection Alive?

I have also tried to add multiple health-chek paths to the manifest file of the HTTP server but this is not handled by Copilot

Comment: I am having the same issue with my microservice I tried to add retry and timeout but it's not able to keep the connection live.